# Cygwin - gcc compilation of symengine error using make - variadic templates

Tags: c++11, gcc, makefile, cygwin, variadic-templates

I wouldn't normally disturb people with a problem like this, but I've been fruitlessly Googling to no result.
I'm installing symengine to my computer via cygwin, and the instructions tell you to do 'cmake .' then 'make'

```
/cygdrive/c/SDPB/sym/symengine/symengine_rcp.h:294:32: warning: variadic templates only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
template<typename T_, typename ...Args>
                        ^
/cygdrive/c/SDPB/sym/symengine/symengine_rcp.h:295:37: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
friend inline RCP<T_> make_rcp( Args&& ...args );
                             ^
/cygdrive/c/SDPB/sym/symengine/symengine_rcp.h:295:48: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
friend inline RCP<T_> make_rcp( Args&& ...args );
```

I realise that this might be a very specific error, and not a common problem, but I was wondering as to how to enable c++11 or gnu++11 via make in this instance?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the c++11 flag missing, as it is used in their own files so cmake should put the right compiler flags in the Makefile. The same way you'd write `g++ -o output.o -c source.c`, if you want c++11 you'd write `g++ -std=c++11 -o output.o -c source.c`. This has to be written in the Makefile, you can't pass it as a command argument.

Comment: That makes sense, however I cannot figure out where I would have to go to edit that in. At no point in the Makefile does it say g++. The only place I can think to go is `# target to build an object file
symengine_rcp.o: 
$(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/symengine.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/symengine.dir/symengine_rcp.o
.PHONY : symengine_rcp.o`

Which when I go to the build.make file, the same issue carries on, and I am left not knowing where to go again. Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Normally in advanced Makefiles, you define the command name and directories/files in variables, so you only need to change it once if you need to change the compiler/directory/file. The variable name usually is `CC` or `CXX` for the compilers. However, the cmake file generated sub-makefiles which the main makefile calls (from what I understand of the line you gave, which seems the right one). For the c++11 flag, there is a variable for that too: it's `CFLAGS` for C or `CXXFLAGS` for C++. If it is defined it _should_ be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a flag at the cmake step first remove `CMakeCache.txt` and then do

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 cmake .
```

To add a flag at the make step, you can do,

```
make CXX_DEFINES=-std=c++11
```

I've opened an issue here, https://github.com/symengine/symengine/issues/826. If you can post the CMake output there, we can fix this in SymEngine itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the issue I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

It might be implemented as cmake define, please check documentation. For example, in some C++ toolkit Geant there is documented option -DGEANT4_BUILD_CXXSTD=ON|OFF (it is OFF by default.) When you pass this option to cmake

```
> cmake -DGEANT4_BUILD_CXXSTD=ON
```

then generated makefile will contain option -std=c++11

Another option is to pass it to make

```
> make CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
```

Last option is to open makefile and check if it contains for CXXFLAGS some defition which could be altered, like

```
> make CXXADDON=-std=c++11
```